# Jquery sliding element down and up with the same link not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, it slides down, but not up. Please could you help me find the error, and also if maybe there is a better way to do this, I have tried slideToggle, but that does not make it possible to check the state of the element, for where using hide and show you can check `$('#my_div').is(':hidden')`.

Here is my code:

```
$("a.advanced_search_toggle").click(function() { 
    if ($("#advanced_search_box").hasClass('closed')) {
        $("#advanced_search_box").slideDown(function(){
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").text('Simple Search');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").removeClass('down_arrow');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").addClass('up_arrow')
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").removeClass('closed');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").addClass('open'); 
        });
    } else {
        $("#advanced_search_box").slideUp(function(){
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").text('Advanced Search');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").removeClass('up_arrow');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").addClass('down_arrow');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").removeClass('open');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").addClass('closed');                       
        });         
    }
    return false;
});
```

Please note that by default I add a class of closed to `#advanced_search_box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to modify the attributes of the link instead of the element.  In addition, [cache](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/efficientjs.shtml) your objects by assigning the objects to a variable, which helps for simpler reference and optimization.  Try the following:

```
$("a.advanced_search_toggle").click(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var box = $("#advanced_search_box");
    if (box.hasClass('closed')) {
        box.slideDown(function(){
            link.text('Simple Search').removeClass('down_arrow').addClass('up_arrow');
            box.removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
        });
    } else {
        box.slideUp(function(){
            link.text('Advanced Search').removeClass('up_arrow').addClass('down_arrow');
            box.removeClass('open').addClass('closed');                    
        });         
    }
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m9XMn/

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this great answer, and thanks for the demo. I see now my mistake, and how to better optimize my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the .removeClass call to "#advanced_search_box" instead of "a.advanced_search_toggle". It's not removing the class name on the element you're checking it for, hence not sliding up, only down.

```
$("a.advanced_search_toggle").click(function() { 
    if ($("#advanced_search_box").hasClass('closed')) {
        $("#advanced_search_box").slideDown(function(){
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").text('Simple Search');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").removeClass('down_arrow');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").addClass('up_arrow')
            $(this).removeClass('closed');
            $(this).addClass('open'); 
        });
    } else {
        $("#advanced_search_box").slideUp(function(){
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").text('Advanced Search');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").removeClass('up_arrow');
            $("a.advanced_search_toggle").addClass('down_arrow');
            $(this).removeClass('open');
            $(this).addClass('closed');                       
        });         
    }
    return false;
});
```